# Filter out a range of characters in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string like `<p>[var @ example] <h1>Title</h1>[visual compose]</p>`I want to filter out all the substrings which are inside square brackets, including the square brackets.

Comment: replaceAll with appropriate regex will do the job. (Do you care about unbalanced or nested brackets? I mean input like: 'a[a[[[[b]a b[b]b')

Comment: @Lesiak I don't have nested brackets. That's why I don't care about them. Also can you give me a sample of code, rather than explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to remove them?

You can do it with `RegExp`, but I would use a parser when html is involved.

One solution is this:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a92f2181191e23ee587d57fb55246c1f

```dart
String filterShortcodes(String input,
    {String opening = '[', String closing = ']'}) {
  assert(opening.runes.length == 1);
  assert(closing.runes.length == 1);
  final openingRune = opening.runes.first;
  final closingRune = closing.runes.first;
  bool filter = false;
  final buf = StringBuffer();
  for (final rune in input.runes) {
    if (filter == false && rune == openingRune) {
      filter = true;
    } else if (filter == true && rune == closingRune) {
      filter = false;
    } else if (!filter) {
      buf.write(String.fromCharCode(rune));
    }
  }
  return buf.toString();
}

void main() {
  var input = '<p>[var @ example] <h1>Title</h1>[visual compose]</p>';
  print(filterShortcodes(input)); // <p> <h1>Title</h1></p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String removeTextBetweenSquareBrackets(String input) {
  return input.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\[.*?\]'), "");
}


void main() {
  print(removeTextBetweenSquareBrackets('<p>[var @ example] <h1>Title</h1>[visual compose]</p>'));
}
```